# Objective-C error while implementing class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, implementation

I have this class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SubscriptionArray : NSObject{
    NSString *title;
    NSString *source;
    NSString *htmlUrl;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *source;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *htmlUrl;

@end
```

and the implementation file is this one:

```
#import "SubscriptionArray.h"

@implementation SubscriptionArray
@synthesize title,source,htmlUrl;

-(void)dealloc{
    [title release];
    [source release];
    [htmlUrl release];
}

@end
```

When I use the class like in this example I get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
  for (NSDictionary *element in subs){
            SubscriptionArray *add;
            add.title=[element objectForKey:@"title"];   //ERROR Happens at this line
            add.source=[element objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"];
            add.htmlUrl=[element objectForKey:@"id"];
            [subscriptions addObject:add];


        }
```

Can someone help me? 
P.S. Subscriptions is a NSMutableArray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate your SubscriptionArray object like so: `SubscriptionArray *add = [[SubscriptionArray alloc] init];`

Your for loop will therefore look something like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *element in subs){
        SubscriptionArray *add = [[SubscriptionArray alloc] init];
        add.title=[element objectForKey:@"title"];
        add.source=[element objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"];
        add.htmlUrl=[element objectForKey:@"id"];
        [subscriptions addObject:add];
        [add release];
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I correct my code and Now I get this error:2011-08-26 17:14:18.102 NewsPad[1204:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7eb2cb0' what does it means? what can I do?

Comment: It seems your element variable refers to an NSSet rather than an NSDictionary. To understand more, we'd need to see the code where subs is defined.

Comment: You need to put `[add release];` at the end of the loop, after adding `add` to `subscriptions`. @paul

Comment: @Josh Yep totally forgot about the release. Added it in to the code :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your SubscriptionArray. i.e.

```
SubscriptionArray *add = [SubscriptionArray new];
```